How to reuse a shiny module that generates a plot an arbitrary number of times?
I am wondering how to re-use a shiny module an arbitrary number of times to allow the user to specify how many plots they want to generate.
In the example below, I have a module mod_inputSelecty_var_ui that allows the user to select  input$y_var.  This input$y_var is then sent to module mod_outputFigure_server which will create output$plot  , which will then by displayed in the ui by the module mod_outputFigure_ui .
Since I want the user to be able to pick4 variables and display 4 plots, I have to call each module 4 times in a different namespace.   I called these namespaces outputDashboardPlot1, outputDashboardPlot2,  outputDashboardPlot3, outputDashboardPlot4.
It works.
What I would like to do is allow the user topick desired number of plots 1 <= n <= 99   instead of  forcing nplots = 4.
It has to be something about using lapply or purrr::map(), but I can't wrap my head around it.
ggplot2::theme_set(theme_minimal(base_size = 16))
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

    mod_inputSelecty_var_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(
      inputId =ns("y_var"),
      label ="y_var",
      choices= colnames(mtcars),
      selected = "mpg",
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  )
}


mod_outputFigure_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput(NS(id, "plot"))
  )
}


mod_outputFigure_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      y_var <- input[["y_var"]]
      y_var_sym <- rlang::sym(y_var)
      message(y_var)
      mtcars %>%
        ggplot(aes(x={{y_var_sym}})) +
        geom_density() +
        labs(title = y_var)
    })
  })
}


ui <- function(request) {
  bslib::page_navbar(
    title = "title",

    nav_panel(
      title ="nav_panel", # dashboard nav_panel -----
      layout_sidebar(
        sidebar =
          bslib::sidebar(
            mod_inputSelecty_var_ui("outputDashboardPlot1"),
            mod_inputSelecty_var_ui("outputDashboardPlot2"),
            mod_inputSelecty_var_ui("outputDashboardPlot3"),
            mod_inputSelecty_var_ui("outputDashboardPlot4")
          ),
        layout_column_wrap(
          width = 1/2,
          height = 300,
          card(card_header("graph1"),
               mod_outputFigure_ui("outputDashboardPlot1"),  full_screen = TRUE
          ),
          card(card_header("graph2"),
               mod_outputFigure_ui("outputDashboardPlot2"),  full_screen = TRUE
          ),
          card(card_header("graph3"),
               mod_outputFigure_ui("outputDashboardPlot3"),  full_screen = TRUE
          ),
          card(card_header("graph4"),
               mod_outputFigure_ui("outputDashboardPlot4"),  full_screen = TRUE
          )
        ) # end layout_column_wrap
      ) # end layoud sidebar

    ) #  end  navpanel
  ) #  end page_navbar

}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_outputFigure_server("outputDashboardPlot1")
  mod_outputFigure_server("outputDashboardPlot2")
  mod_outputFigure_server("outputDashboardPlot3")
  mod_outputFigure_server("outputDashboardPlot4")
}

shinyApp(ui,server)



EDIT:   as usual with rubber duck debugging, writing this example down led me to the purrr::map() hypothesis.  some google led me there, which looks promising https://tbradley1013.github.io/2018/08/10/create-a-dynamic-number-of-ui-elements-in-shiny-with-purrr/
